# Open "Add Attachments" popup in new tab - Is it possible?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, attachments

Is there a setting in SharePoint 2013 that will allow the popup window that comes up when you go to add an attachment to an item in a list in a new tab instead of the popup modal?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB setting in SharePoint for this requirement.

If you want to change the open behavior for the “**Attach File**” button in the list, you will need to use custom solution, which will be rather complicated since the item needs to be selected first.